# Query row in mysql with duplicated row

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql for my project. I have two table: `user` and `img`. And this is schema for them.

```
User
id: int (AI)
username: varchar(50)
password: varchar(50)

Img
id: int (AI)
user_id: int
path: varchar(100)
```

I know that mysql not support array like nosql, so i must use two table to store multiple image per one user.

The proplem: When i get all user with their image, it's duplicate data, the query like this:

```
SELECT u.*, i.path FROM user u INNER JOIN img i ON u.id=i.user_id ORDER BY u.id DESC
```

I know the reason, but i can't solve it, data must be like this

> User || Img
>
> 5    || 897696987.jpg, Jghd8867D.jpg
>
> 8    || 8768788Kd.jpg

But is show:

> User || Img
>
> 5    || 897696987.jpg
>
> 5    || Jghd8867D.jpg
>
> 8    || 8768788Kd.jpg

How can i do to make it better?
Thank you!

Comment: It's correct display. What problem about response data?

Comment: Because i response data to client like this: `obj{id:5, username: "test", img: [{id: 1, path: sss.jpg,{id: 2, path: aaa.jpg}}] }`

Comment: use loop and put data in your array follow your requirement.

Comment: ah, i know how to do it, because i use this way to solve my problem, but this is the good solution? Agh ... mysql so bad for this, maybe i will use MongoDb, but project must be use mySql

Comment: ok try my answer

Comment: Yeah, may i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT u.*, GROUP_CONCAT(i.path) as i.path FROM user u INNER JOIN img i ON u.id=i.user_id GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY u.id DESC
```